# Linux firefox error: Server not found

Tags: networking, firefox

Again. It was suggested that I create a new question so here it is.

I am trying to open firefox (this is happening with every browser, really) and it is giving me this error:

> (i) Server not found
>
> Firefox can't find the server at www.reddit.com
>
> Check the address for typing errors such as **ww**.example.com instead of **www**.example.com
>
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
>
> If your computer network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.

Reddit, of course, is just an example. Reddit isn't and wasn't down at the time, so that can't be the problem. I tested it with other sites such as nationstates.com, yahoo, google, etc.

Here is the network information that was given to me by the terminal and the wireless info script:

Wireless info - http://pastebin.com/MUKJ3Bwx

lspci - http://pastebin.com/6eKP1ik7

Comment: What did to to determinate the root cause of the problem ? (like: check with ping ? checking Name resolving is working ? -->  check with: ping www.google.com is working ? if not tried: ping 8.8.8.8 ?)

Comment: @ikj I wasn't entirely sure what the root cause of the problem was. I had no typing errors, my network connection was fine (except for having to reconnect to my wifi every time I turned the computer on), I don't have a firewall or proxy up that would block firefox, and when I pinged google, it gave me this: "64 bytes from jm-in-fl03.1e100.net" on loop, but this was after I unplugged my wireless adapter and then plugged it back in. I then thought it my wifi was fine, tried accessing google, it gave me the same error, then told me that it was an unknown host. This adapter is fairly old.

Comment: Do you think it could be the adapter that's causing my problem? Edit: I tried pinging 8.8.8 and it told me that the destination host is unreachable

Comment: " I tried pinging 8.8.8 and it told me that the destination host is unreachable" - so this makes clear you don't have a working network connection. As I was looking to your "lspci output" I spotted iwconfig and routing information. what happens if you ping to your default gateway "192.168.1.1" ?

Comment: It's not 8.8.8, it's 8.8.8.8

Comment: @Jos It told me the same thing.

Comment: @lkj I tried doing that and it kept adding a 4 onto the end of 192.168.1.1. Is that normal? It also still told me that the destination host was unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest Ubuntu release, set your DNS servers to your modem IP and Google (`8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`). This option is located in `System Settings > Network` on the  `IPV4 tab`. To add DNS servers, click on the small icon on the right of the `DNS server` field.

Comment: @Gansheim @alfredo87 For the latest Ubuntu release, I set my DNS servers to my modem IP and Google `(8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)`, but it doesn't work. Nothing work, what should I do?